# Azure Account 'default' Azure AD Instance

Tags: azure

I have a very simple Azure lab set up.  A resource group with a virtual machine that I can get to over the internet.  I wanted to start poking around with "Azure Active Directory" but before I added anything, I noticed (using the az cli) there is already an instance of AD in my account by default.

I can't seem to access (or see) this AzureAD instance using the portal. If I wanted to ad Azure AD functions to my resources, should I be using this AD instance, or should I use a separate one?

tia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we signup to azure for the first time, by default azure ad account will be created with onmicrosoft.com domain and
we can directly access Azure AD from the Azure portal and form there we can manage user accounts, permissions related to azure resources, add/remove enterprise applications and other operations related to Azure Active Directory.

if in case if you want to create your own tenant, You may follow the steps as mentioned here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant

And at the same time If you sign up with an email belonging to a domain which has a verified AAD Tenant it will create your subscription under that Tenant, which can drastically reduce your privileges within the domain and you will be having limited access to manage azure active directory.